# How Can I keep the dropdown last selected on refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

I have this HTML

```
<select id="drpRequestCategories" class="form-control" Width="100%">
    <option value="-1">All</option>
</select>
```

and here is the function I fill the Select from it

```
function filldropdownlistcategory(res) {             
    var test = $.parseJSON(res.d);
    $("#drpRequestCategories").empty();
    $(test).each(function () {               
        var option = $('<option />');
        option.attr('value', this.ServiceID).text(this.ServiceName);
        $('#drpRequestCategories').append(option);
    });
}
```

when I click on Search button on my page 
1-it clear this dropdownlist but I need to keep the last selected value.
2- I call this function on every treeview node change so when I remove this

```
$("#drpRequestCategories").empty();
```

it doesn't remove the old dropdown values but append the new values to the old .

Comment: Could u share a demo of this?

Comment: sadly I can't simulate the all scenario, but any part aren't clear ?@Vijaykrish93

Comment: when u want to save last selected option on page refresh ...go for session storage of localStorage mechanisms

Comment: and what about I want also, the all select ?

Comment: U want to remove the 'all' option as well?

Comment: I can't understand you well, could you provide me a syntax ? and how can I use localstorage ?

Comment: What exactly u want to acheive....u want to prefil the select box with last selected option right?...and also u want to empty the box on page refresh

Comment: No I want to empty the box on every nodechanged which call this function , but I want to keep the last values of the all 'select' which filled before the submit or refresh

Answer (score 0):

Ok first using localstorage set a key holding the last selected item ,while every node change first empty the select box and use the localstorage item to fill the box again

```
//Add the onchange listener for the select box
  $("#drpRequestCategories").on('change',function(evt){
    var optionSelected=evt.target.value;
    localStorage.setItem("recent",optionSelected);
  }
//Now your function
  function filldropdownlistcategory(res){
    //empty the box
    $("#drpRequestCategories").empty();
    $(test).each(function () {               
    var option = $('<option />');
    option.attr('value', this.ServiceID).text(this.ServiceName);
    $('#drpRequestCategories').append(option);
    });
   //Once U have appended the options attach the previous list to the select box
   var prevOptions=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("options"));
   for(var key in options){
     var option=$('<option />')
     option.attr("value",options[key]).text(options[key])
     $("#drpRequestCategories").append(option)
   }
   //Now Select the Last selected option
   var lastSelected=localStorage.getItem("recent");
   $("#drpRequestCategories").val(lastSelected);
   //Once all the options are populated call the storeOptions Function
   storeOptions();   
 }
 //Function to store the options
 function storeOptions(){
  var options=$("#drpRequestCategories").children();
  var obj={};
  for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
  var optionText=options[0].value || options[0].innerHTML //Depends on         what you want
  //update the obj
  obj["option"+i]=optionText;    
}
//Now Store them in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("options",JSON.stringify(obj))//stringify will convert the object into a string
 }
```

Comment: Sorry For being as a headache  pain for you, but where shall I call the function optionsChanged??

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping, when I try it gives me the first value with null then fill the other values correctly, I will debug and tell you the result

Comment: Ok make sure the option value is correctly added to the localstorage item

Comment: Well now here is the all scenario ,
I want to save the last all select list with last option value  , but it save the last option value only and didn't save the all select with its selected option , hope you can understand me

Comment: Do u want the option '<option>All</option>' inside the select box all the time?

Comment: yes , here is another question can I save all the dropdownlist?

Comment: yes you can get the values of list and store it inside the same localstorage key......gimme a demo so that i can give u what u want

Comment: I don't know how to make a demo because I get data from server side , so could you help me and tell how can I save the all dropdownlist ?

Comment: U can add it anywhere inside the script..but make sure u add these after filldropdown function is executed

Comment: ok, thanks , now I can Keep the last loaded list on refresh but I can't make it appears the last selected option at the first

Comment: but it fill the value twice , one from the original load and the other selected value from append

Comment: yes, It will called twice now 
one in the page load and the other on treeview selected node changed

Comment: That shuld be fine right......add the last updated code inside the function and call it inside dropDownlist function....whats the issue thr?

Comment: it worked as I want exactly but , when I want it do when  change the all dropdownlist values it return me to the <option value="-1">all</option> again what already happens is appears the box empty , but fill it correctly